# Oracle XML data select in SQLExecute Statement

Tags: sql

Following query is returning null in Mathematica.

t = "select xmlelement(\"test\",1) as test from dual";
SQLExecute[conn, t]

It should retrun 1 as result but it is returing NUll value.
How can I rertive xml data stored in the database using mathematica??

Comment: You might try casting the XML to _varchar_, e.g. `select cast(xmlelement("test",1) as varchar(255)) as test from dual`.